# Are questions about MLA formatting on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I have a question about in-text citations for my MLA paper, but before I ask it on Writing SE, I feel like it isn't exactly on topic.  Would it be more suitable on English SE?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure. We even have a tag with 80 questions in it. See [mla](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mla)

Comment: Haha, didn't even realize that tag existed.